# SwiftUI - Async Await con cancelación de tarea

Tags: async-await, swiftui

estoy intentado adaptar el siguiente código que uso combine para generar una lista de 5 números aleatorios, pero antes de usar el framework combine hacerlo 100% con swiftUI y async/await

```swift
import SwiftUI
import Combine

enum RandomNumberError: Error {
    case invalidNumber
}

enum RandomNumberState {
    case idle
    case success([Int])
    case failure(Error)
    case working
    
    func isWorking() -> Bool {
        if case .working = self {
            return true
        }
        return false
    }
}

class MyViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published private var randomNumberState: RandomNumberState = .idle
    private var randomNumberTask: Task<Void, Never>?
    
    var randomNumbersPublisher: Published<RandomNumberState>.Publisher {
        $randomNumberState
    }
    
    func generateRandomNumbers() {
        
        randomNumberTask = Task {
            do {
                randomNumberState = .working
                print("generando numeros")
                var randomNumbers: [Int] = []
                for _ in 0..<5 {
                    try Task.checkCancellation()
                    
                    let number = Int.random(in: 1...100)
                    if (1...3).contains(number) {
                        throw RandomNumberError.invalidNumber
                    } else {
                        randomNumbers.append(number)
                    }
                    
                }
                // Delay for a short interval between number generations
                let duration = UInt64(3 * 1_000_000_000)
                try await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: duration)
                
                print("numeros:", randomNumbers)
                randomNumberState = .success(randomNumbers)
            } catch {
                if Task.isCancelled {
                    print("cancelación")
                    randomNumberState = .idle
                } else {
                    randomNumberState = .failure(error)
                }

            }
        }
    }
    
    func cancelRandomNumberGeneration() {
        randomNumberTask?.cancel()
    }
}

struct RandomNumberView: View {
    @StateObject private var myViewModel = MyViewModel()
    @State private var candidatesResult: RandomNumberState?
    @State private var subscription: AnyCancellable?
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Spacer()
            if let candidates = candidatesResult {
                switch candidates {
                case .idle:
                    
                    Text("Presiona el botón para generar números aleatorios.")
                case .success(let numbers):
                    List(numbers, id: \.self) { number in
                        Text("\(number)")
                    }
                    .transition(.opacity) // Fade in and fade out animation
                case .failure(let error):
                    Text("Error Feature: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                        .foregroundColor(.red)
                case .working:
                    ProgressView("Generando números...")
                    
                    Button("Cancelar") {
                        myViewModel.cancelRandomNumberGeneration()
                    }
                    .padding()
                }
            }
            
            Spacer()
            Button("Generar números aleatorios") {
                myViewModel.generateRandomNumbers()
            }
            .disabled(candidatesResult?.isWorking() == true)
            .padding()
        }
        .task {
            subscription = myViewModel.randomNumbersPublisher
                .sink { result in
                    withAnimation {
                        candidatesResult = result
                    }
                }
        }
        .onDisappear {
            subscription?.cancel()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacer lo que quieres con un `AsyncThrowingStream`

```
actor MyViewModel {
    func generateRandomNumbers() -> AsyncThrowingStream<RandomNumberState, Error> {
        .init { continuation in
            let task = Task { //Crear el inner task
                do {
                    continuation.yield(.working) //Continuar con in yield
                    print("generando numeros")
                    var randomNumbers: [Int] = []
                    for _ in 0..<5 {
                        try Task.checkCancellation()
                        
                        let number = Int.random(in: 1...100)
                        if (1...3).contains(number) {
                            throw RandomNumberError.invalidNumber
                        } else {
                            randomNumbers.append(number)
                        }
                        
                    }
                    // Delay for a short interval between number generations
                    let duration = UInt64(3 * 1_000_000_000)
                    try await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: duration)
                    
                    print("numeros:", randomNumbers)
                    continuation.yield(.success(randomNumbers))
                    continuation.finish() // Finalizar
                } catch {
                    continuation.yield(.failure(error)) //Esto es duplicado de "tirar" un error
                    continuation.finish(throwing: error) //Finalizar tirano el error
                }
            }
            continuation.onTermination = { reason in
                task.cancel() //Cancelar el inner task
                switch reason {
                case .finished(_):
                    break //Si el task finalizo no hacer nada
                case .cancelled:
                    continuation.yield(.idle) //Regresar a idle si el task es cancelada por el usuario.
                @unknown default:
                    continuation.yield(.idle) //Regresar a idle si el task termino por also desconocido.
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Y cambiar to `View` a usar un `stream` en vez de una subscription.

```
struct RandomNumberView: View {
    //Cambiar el VM a in actor
    private let myViewModel = MyViewModel()
    //Empezar con idle envez de nil
    @State private var state: RandomNumberState = .idle
    //Variable que controla cuando `.task` esta corriendo
    @State private var generando: Bool = false //Duplicado de idle y working
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Spacer()
            switch state {
            case .idle:
                Text("Presiona el botón para generar números aleatorios.")
            case .success(let numbers):
                List(numbers, id: \.self) { number in
                    Text("\(number)")
                }
                .transition(.opacity) // Fade in and fade out animation
            case .failure(let error):
                Text("Error Feature: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                    .foregroundColor(.red)
            case .working:
                ProgressView("Generando números...")
                Button("Cancelar") {
                    generando = false //Cancela el task
                }
            }
            
            
            Spacer()
            Button("Generar números aleatorios") { // El mismo botton genera o cancela
                generando = true
            }
            .disabled(generando)
            .padding()
            .task(id: generando) {
                guard generando else {
                    return
                }
                let stream = await myViewModel.generateRandomNumbers()
                do{
                    for try await status in stream {
                        state = status
                    }
                } catch {
                    print(" \(error)") // Cachar un error.
                }
                generando = false
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Esto se puede simplificar a una simple `async await` si utilizas `generando` como indicativo de `idle` y `working`. Algo como...

```
actor MyViewModel {
    func generateRandomNumbers() async throws -> [Int] {
        do {
            print("generando numeros")
            var randomNumbers: [Int] = []
            for _ in 0..<5 {
                try Task.checkCancellation()
                
                let number = Int.random(in: 1...100)
                if (1...3).contains(number) {
                    throw RandomNumberError.invalidNumber
                } else {
                    randomNumbers.append(number)
                }
                
            }
            // Delay for a short interval between number generations
            let duration = UInt64(3 * 1_000_000_000)
            try await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: duration)
            
            print("numeros:", randomNumbers)
            return randomNumbers
        } catch {
            throw error
        }
    }
}
struct RandomNumberView: View {
    //Cambiar el VM a in actor
    private let myViewModel = MyViewModel()
    //Empezar con idle envez de nil
    @State private var state: RandomNumberState = .idle
    //Variable que controla cuando `.task` esta corriendo
    @State private var generando: Bool = false //Duplicado de idle y working
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Spacer()
            switch state {
            case .idle:
                Text("Presiona el botón para generar números aleatorios.")
            case .success(let numbers):
                List(numbers, id: \.self) { number in
                    Text("\(number)")
                }
                .transition(.opacity) // Fade in and fade out animation
            case .failure(let error):
                Text("Error Feature: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                    .foregroundColor(.red)
            case .working:
                ProgressView("Generando números...")
                Button("Cancelar") {
                    generando = false //Cancela el task
                }
            }
            
            
            Spacer()
            Button("Generar números aleatorios") { // El mismo botton genera o cancela
                generando = true
            }
            .disabled(generando)
            .padding()
            .task(id: generando) {
                guard generando else {
                    state = .idle
                    return
                }
                state = .working
                do{
                    let numbers = try await myViewModel.generateRandomNumbers()
                    state = .success(numbers)
                } catch {
                    state = .failure(error)
                    print(" \(error)") // Cachar un error.
                }
                generando = false
            }
        }
    }
}
```